# Tabular+dcolumn+mathspec — columns overlapping

Tags: tables, mathspec, dcolumn

I would like to typeset a table using the `D` column type as described in the [`dcolumn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package.  When I combine this with `\setmathfont(Digits){Gotham Narrow Light}` I get overlapping columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Gotham Narrow Medium]{Gotham Narrow Book}
\setmathrm{Gotham Narrow Book}
\setmathfont(Latin){Gotham Narrow Book}
% works fine
%\setmathfont(Digits){Monaco}
\setmathfont(Digits){Arial}
% causes column overlapping
\setmathfont(Digits){Gotham Narrow Light}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
\begin{array}{d{1.3}|d{1.5}|d{1.4}|d{1.4}|d{1.4}}
1.500 & 2.75000 & 0.5000 & 0.2500 & 1.2500 \\
1.750 & 2.93750 & 0.2500 & 0.0625 & 1.0625 \\
1.900 & 2.99000 & 0.1000 & 0.0100 & 1.0100 \\
1.990 & 2.99990 & 0.0100 & 0.0001 & 1.0001 \\
1.999 & 3.00000 & 0.0010 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 \\
2.000 & 1.00000 & 0.0000 & 2.0000 & 3.0000 \\
2.001 & 3.00000 & 0.0010 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 \\
2.010 & 2.99990 & 0.0100 & 0.0001 & 1.0001 \\
2.100 & 2.99000 & 0.1000 & 0.0100 & 1.0100 \\
2.250 & 2.93750 & 0.2500 & 0.0625 & 1.0625 \\
2.500 & 2.75000 & 0.5000 & 0.2500 & 1.2500 \\
\end{array}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

I've tried with other monospace and proportional fonts and they seem to work fine.  Is something wrong with Gotham?

Answer (score 1):

My best workaround so far is to substitute:

```
\setmathfont(Digits)[Numbers={Monospaced}]{Gotham Narrow Light}
```

The side effect is that *all* digits in the entire document are now monospaced.

Comment: Did you consider setting the `\fontspec` at the beginning of each table-like environment?

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I tried `\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced}}` and `\fontspec[Numbers={Monospaced}]{Gotham Narrow Light}` in several places but nothing changed.   `\setmathfont` doesn't work outside the preamble